# Remove/Add Line Breaks after Specific String using Sublime Text

Tags: string, text-editor, sublimetext2

Using Sublime Text 2 - Is it possible to **insert a line break**/text return after a specific String in a text file e.g. by using the *Find* ‣ *Replace* tool?

(Bonus question: Is it possible to remove all line breaks after a specific String)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Here's how you'd do it on a Mac:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *type string* > <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>ESC</kbd> > <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> > *line break*

and [Windows/Linux](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection) (untested):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *type string*   > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> > <kbd>ESC</kbd> > <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> > *line break*

The important part being <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to select all matches.
Once you've selected the text you're looking for, you can use the provided multiple cursors to do whatever text manipulation you want.

Protip: you can manually instantiate multiple cursors by using <kbd>Command</kbd>+*click* (or <kbd>Control</kbd>+*click*) to achieve similar results.

Comment: THis seems to break down when I try it with regular expression searches like `(this|that|the other)`

Comment: @Amanda try Option+Enter instead of ESC (shortcut for the "Find All" button).

Comment: It's worth mentioning this same tactic works great for removing line breaks that end with a particular pattern, such as binary blobs in Windows .reg files: instead of right arrow + line break, try left arrow + delete until you get the union you want.

Also, your Windows hotkeys are correct. I don't have a Linux instance handy to test with, but it's probably fine.

Comment: Any clue on how to do this on a selection instead of the whole file? Control+Command+G clears the selection and finds all in the whole file.

Comment: Seems so obvious now... thanks a million! Also, @Mauro - I'm on Windows, and I can used ctrl + d to select the next iteration of the selection. Perhaps the same functionality exists on MAC with Command + d ? You may have to press it numerous times to go through the whole file

Comment: @shanehoban Ohh! That was it. I changed the Cmd+D shortcut a long ago to delete a complete line like I do on Eclipse.

Comment: The Ctrl-CMD-G plus left/right arrow is a magic! :) I would never image it could be used this way.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 69):

Using the ***Find - Replace tool***, this can be accomplished in two different ways:

1. Click in the ***Replace field*** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a newline (the field should resize but it doesn't, so it is hard to see the newline inserted).
2. Inside the ***Find - Replace tool***, activate the ***S&R regex mode*** (first icon on the left <kbd>.*</kbd>, keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to activate/deactivate it).
3. Type **`\n`** in the ***Replace field*** wherever you want to insert a newline.

Both solutions also work if you want to find newlines, just do it in the *Find field*.

Comment: Can't find the S&R regex mode but the first solution works well!

Comment: @hhh: If you open the ***Find-Replace tool***, ***S&R regex mode*** is the first icon on the left of the tool menu (looks like .*)

Comment: @veducm Yes I can see that icon corresponding to the search field but not for the replace field. Maybe it is because I have an unregistered version?

Comment: @hhh there is only one icon and when enabled it applies to both fields.

Comment: @veducm thanks. finally an easy solution to an easy problem. You know why we need the regular expression enabled though? for the replacing string

Answer (score 8):

Edit->Lines->Join Line (Ctrl+J)

Comment: This works for me in the Atom editor! Select the paragraph and *Ctrl+J*.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use multiple cursors.  See [the unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html#multiple-selections), or this [nice tutorial](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/multiple-cursors-and-incremental-search/).  Here's some brief instructions to set you on your way:

1. Put the cursor on the string of interest.
2. Type <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Windows/Linux) to select the current instance of the string.
3. Type <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Windows/Linux) to select successive instances of the string.
4. Alternately, type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to select **all** instances of your string.
5. Now you have multiple cursors, so insert or remove your newline as you please.
6. (type <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit multiple cursor mode.)

Have fun!